# java 8 iterate over list and compare with another list by index

Tags: java, java-8

I am new to Java 8 and am trying to use the for loop with the java 8 syntax.
I have 2 lists - would like to iterate over the first list and compare with a  specific index of another list. I can easily do this in Java1.7 syntax as follows.

```
List<String> expectedValueList = dataTable.asList(String.class);
String result  = IOUtils.toString(myUtil.getResult().StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
List<String> rows = Arrays.asList(result.split("\n");
  for(int ii=1;ii<rows.size();ii++){ //Skipping header value
      String row = rows.get(ii);
      String[] strToks = row.split(",");
      String actualVal = strToks[10];
      String expectedVal = expectedValueList[ii];
      Assert.assertEquals(expectedVal,actualVal);
   }
```

I would like to do the above using java8 syntax and am getting lost. 
Thank you

Comment: The syntax for a for loop has not changed from java 7 to 8....

Comment: What specifically are you trying to change? There's nothing different here between the two versions. Oracle would get slammed into the ground by every dev on the planet if they were to completely change Java syntax between two versions.

Comment: Java 8 added the Stream API as an alternative, but your Java 7 code will still work. Is your question about whether it can be expressed more elegantly with Java 8 features? If functionality is all that matters, you can just continue with the existing code.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes-  I would like to know if I could express the same in a more elegant fashion using Java 8 features. I tried using stream but not sure how to keep track of the index of the loop.

Comment: Trying to use streams with anything that cares about indexes is likely to be much more awkward than just not using streams.

Comment: This code does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean the java Stream API. Your basic problem is comparing two list.

If the ***order doesn't matter*** the the stream api comes handy and you can do t like this:

```
rows.stream().map(e -> e.split(",")[10]).allMatch(expectedValueList::contains);
```

But if the ***order matters***, all you can do is just modify the iteration a bit and use `IntStream.range` for example, but you still access the elements with the `.get(index)`

```
IntStream.range(1, rows.size())
  .allMatch(i -> 
    rows.get(i).split(",")[10].compareTo(expectedValueList.get(i)) == 0
  );
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using stream but am not sure how to keep track of the index of the loop.Essentially would like to re-write my code using Java8 features